# How to learn Microsoft Azure particularly Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

My recent work involved Azure B2C and I am really fascinated and confused at the same time. AFAIK, to perform any kind of work in Azure B2C, you need Azure subscription and create resources.

My question is, How can I explore/lab Azure B2C Policies and practise without spending too much (I don't mind to spend money but don't know much it will cost).

Answer (score 1):

AAD and B2C are [free](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/) at the base level.

At the end of this post, there are a number of [resources](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-custom-policies-in-azure-ad-b2c-eb63b508a075).